# Getting all phone numbers stored in the database using foreach loop in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have phone numbers stored in the database, I want to retrieve all phone numbers using `foreach` loop and assign them to variable and send bulk sms, but problem is, I am getting only one number from database. Here is my code:

```
    // GET: Members/SendBatch
    public ActionResult SendBatch()
    {

        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SendBatch(Membership member)
    {
        var db = new ChurchContext();
        StreamReader objReader;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        string mess = member.Message;
        string cell = member.Cell;
        string pass = "xxxx";
        string user = "xxxx";
        string selectministries = member.SelectMinistries;
        string pathtoministries = "";

        pathtoministries = GetMinisry(selectministries);

        if (pathtoministries == "Youth")
        {

            var youthtable = from e in db.Youths
                             select e;
            var Entyouth = youthtable.ToList();


            foreach (Youth y in Entyouth)
            {
                string youthcell = y.ContactMobile.ToString();
                cell = youthcell;


            }


        }

      string baseurl = "http://bulksms.2way.co.za/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0?" +
     "username=" + user + "&" +
     "password=" + pass + "&" +
     "message=" + mess + "&" +
     "msisdn=" + cell;

        WebRequest wrGETURL;
        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(baseurl);
        try
        {
            Stream objStream;
            objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
            objReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }

        return View("Index", member);

    }


    public static string GetMinisry(string ministry)
    {
        string membership = "";


        switch (ministry)
        {
            case "Youth":
                membership = "Youth";
                break;
            case "Children":
                membership = "Children";
                break;

            case "Men":
                membership = "Men";
                break;

            case "Women":
                membership = "Women";
                break;

            case "Visitors":
                membership = "Visitors";
                break;
            case "Members":
                membership = "Members";
                break;

        }

        return membership;
    }
```

I would like to get all the phone numbers and assigned them to cell variable and then to sms api and send bulk sms.

Comment: You want to do all kinds of things, but you just keep assigning values to the same single variable _cell_. Just do what you want to do in your for-each loop. You are getting everything from your database, but you are throwing it all away (except the last one...)

Comment: Because you are overwriting the value of cell variable inside the loop for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (dirty but will do the job):

```
    string mess = member.Message;
    string cell = member.Cell;
    List<string> cellNumbers = new List<string>(); //LIST OF NUMBERs
    string pass = "xxxx";
    string user = "xxxx";
    string selectministries = member.SelectMinistries;
    string pathtoministries = "";

    pathtoministries = GetMinisry(selectministries);

    if (pathtoministries == "Youth")
    {

        var youthtable = from e in db.Youths
                         select e;
        var Entyouth = youthtable.ToList();


        foreach (Youth y in Entyouth)
        {
            string youthcell = y.ContactMobile.ToString();
            cell = youthcell;
            cellNumbers.add(cell);


        }


    }
   foreach(string number in cellNumbers) // send all the sms
   {
      string baseurl = "http://bulksms.2way.co.za/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0?" +
     "username=" + user + "&" +
     "password=" + pass + "&" +
     "message=" + mess + "&" +
     "msisdn=" + number;

        WebRequest wrGETURL;
        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(baseurl);
        try
        {
            Stream objStream;
            objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
            objReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also working very well, it does get all the numbers  from database and i am able to send messages to all numbers with bulk sms, you save my day.

Comment: you're welcome. If I may suggest, divide in two functions the retrieval of the numbers, and the batch SMS. It will be easier to debug. If you find our answers useful please upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a cycle where you override `cell` in each iteration and even though `cell` received all the values you need, all were overriden by the next one, except for the very last one. When the cycle is finished, you are sending the request using the very last value of `cell`. This is why you had the illusion that you have got a single value. Actually you have got all the values, but made the mistake of overriding them before using them. The solution is to send the request inside the cycle instead of after the cycle, like this:

```
// GET: Members/SendBatch
public ActionResult SendBatch()
{

    return View();
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SendBatch(Membership member)
{
    var db = new ChurchContext();
    StreamReader objReader;
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    string mess = member.Message;
    string cell = member.Cell;
    string pass = "xxxx";
    string user = "xxxx";
    string selectministries = member.SelectMinistries;
    string pathtoministries = "";

    pathtoministries = GetMinisry(selectministries);

    if (pathtoministries == "Youth")
    {

        var youthtable = from e in db.Youths
                         select e;
        var Entyouth = youthtable.ToList();


        foreach (Youth y in Entyouth)
        {
            string youthcell = y.ContactMobile.ToString();
            cell = youthcell;



  string baseurl = "http://bulksms.2way.co.za/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0?" +
 "username=" + user + "&" +
 "password=" + pass + "&" +
 "message=" + mess + "&" +
 "msisdn=" + cell;

    WebRequest wrGETURL;
    wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(baseurl);
    try
    {
        Stream objStream;
        objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
        objReader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }

    return View("Index", member);

        }


    }
}


public static string GetMinisry(string ministry)
{
    string membership = "";


    switch (ministry)
    {
        case "Youth":
            membership = "Youth";
            break;
        case "Children":
            membership = "Children";
            break;

        case "Men":
            membership = "Men";
            break;

        case "Women":
            membership = "Women";
            break;

        case "Visitors":
            membership = "Visitors";
            break;
        case "Members":
            membership = "Members";
            break;

    }

    return membership;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, its working nicely, i am able to retrieve all the numbers from database and send bulk sms.

Comment: @Haro you are welcome. If this answer solved your problem, you might consider accepting it as the correct answer to let future visitors find the solution in similar problems with a single glance on this page.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: @Haro to the left of an answer at a question you asked you will find a gray checkbox. If you click on that, you accept an answer. An accepted answer has that checkbox greened so visitors see whether there was an accepted correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, your answers solved my problem, hope future visitors to this page with similar problem will get help quickly.